# Excel 2016 Vlookup Function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with Excel's Vlookup function.
I have 2 worksheets. On the first there's a Company Code, on the second I need to find values based on the company code. The relevant code is:

```
Dim Compcode, AUC, OB As String
Dim WS1, WS2 As Worksheet
Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet")
Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Compcode = WS1.Cells(2, 1).Value 'Company code WS1 A2

AUC = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Compcode, WS2.Range("A2:C30"), 2, False)
OB = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Compcode, WS2.Range("A2:C30"), 3, False)
```

I've tried to modify the Dim for each of the variables and the Vlookup function itself, but I always get to the same error message:

Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: It shouldn't be affecting your code, but you should really declare `Compcode` and `AUC` to be `String`, and `WS1` to be `Worksheet` - at the moment you are declaring them to be `Variant` (i.e. use `Dim Compcode As String, AUC As String, OB As String` and `Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet`).  And, FWIW, your code works for me.

Comment: Is the Company Code in `WS2.Range("A2:C30") numeric or text (including numbers formatted as text)?

Comment: Everything is text-based, there isn't a  number in any of the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be in many places. Anyhow obviously, VLOOKUP is a bit picky on numbers and strings, thus the `Compcode` should be a `Variant`

Something like this would work out:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim Compcode        As Variant
    Dim AUC             As String
    Dim OB              As String

    Dim WS1             As Worksheet
    Dim WS2             As Worksheet

    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet")
    Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    Compcode = WS1.Cells(2, 1).Value

    Dim rngRange As Range

    Set rngRange = WS2.Range("A2:C30")

    AUC = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Compcode, rngRange, 2, False)
    OB = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Compcode, rngRange, 3, False)

End Sub
```

You should declare explicitly every variable, this is not `c++/c` to declare them with a comma and to hope that the VBEditor would understand.

I have also changed the formula to a range.

Comment: I also thought so, until I have tried my code with a string, @YowE3K. Change `Compcode` to string and try it. It would fail. I get `1004` in that case.

Comment: It works with `String` (if you are searching for text), but if you have numeric values then the `String` won't match the numbers.  But that will give a 1004 error, not a 438 error.  So **IF** `'Main Sheet'!A2` is numeric, and the lookup range is numeric, your change will stop the 1004 error.

Comment: I've tried the changes, but I still ran into an error: as the Compcode is a string (ABC, ABD, etc), I suppose I'll need to add a numeric value for each string to make it work?

Comment: @Thrazzon - try it once again. I have change the `Compcode` to `Variant`, it should now take both `String` and numbers.

Comment: @Thrazzon - if it still does not work, take a look at the worksheets. I have indexed them `1`,`2` to be easier for me, but at your side its better to return them back to `Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet")`

Comment: @Vityata Thank you for your help, the code works now.

Comment: @Thrazzon - yuppie! :)

Answer (score 4):

`WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` is very volatile to the inputs and can throw runtime errors easily, as you've encountered.

Your issue could be one of a number of things but my suggested solution would be to just use `Find` instead:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Compcode As Variant, AUC As Variant, OB As Variant
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet

    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet")
    Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Compcode = WS1.Cells(2, 1).Value 'Company code WS1 A2

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = WS2.Range("A2:C30").Find(Compcode, , , xlWhole)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        AUC = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
        OB = rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `VLookup` works fine with a `Range` for the location to be searched.  [Table_array - two or more columns of data. Use a reference to a range or a range name.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-vlookup-method-excel)

Comment: @YowE3K, I never liked `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` anyway... updated answer

Comment: One more vote for the group of people, who never liked & always avoid the `VLookup` as well...